# CSS3 Animation polyfill

Tags: css, css-transitions, polyfills

I'm looking to get a CSS3 animation to work; works fine in all major browsers but IE9 and older (no surprise there). So without further ado, here's the CSS :

```
#grosse_photo {
    /*...*/
    -webkit-animation: photoFade 12s infinite;
    -moz-animation:photoFade 12s infinite;
    -ms-animation: photoFade 12s infinite;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -o-animation-iteration-count:1;
}
    @-webkit-keyframes photoFade {
        0%   { opacity: 0.0; }
        100% { opacity: 1.0; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes photoFade {
        0%   { opacity: 0.0; }
        100% { opacity: 1.0; }
    }
    @-o-keyframes photoFade {
        0%   { opacity: 0.0; }
        100% { opacity: 1.0; }
    }
    @keyframes photoFadee {
        0%   { opacity: 0.0; }
        100% { opacity: 1.0; }
    }
```

I used the `-ms` prefix thinking it would react like `-webkit`, but obviously IE (lte 9) didn't cooperate.

I also need elements to slide in, but since IE won't cooperate, I'm thinking I'm forgetting an obvious polyfill other than [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Though not optimal, I've seen many refer to jQuery alternatives, though I am still looking for a snippet which will allow for different animations at different times and speeds.

Comment: Kinda off topic but your code is a case for using a polyfill for generating browser prefixes (-moz-... etc.) so that you don't need to write all of them every time.

Comment: Actually, I have nothing against using a polyfill; I'm just reusing the original code from html5please.com and changing the values. Snippets are cool for that. This being said, I don't mind working with either solution, polyfill of not. Upside, this method ensures I don't forget the polyfill anywhere, or it doesn't work anymore; newer browsers drop the prefixes, so I only get support for older browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is a direct polyfill for animations, that you don't introduce the animation commands by javascript.

For that you can go to jquery animate(), or you can try this one, more new:
http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/web-animations.html

If you need something for transition fallbacks, you can try:
https://github.com/addyosmani/css3-transition-fallbacks

Comment: Sorry, looks like addy took it down. I added a github repo that has fallbacks for transitions

Answer (score 0):

IExplorer doesn't have opacity option, it has 
filter:alpha(opacity=77);
which is basicly the same just compability for IE

Comment: The question is about CSS3 Animation's polyfill, not the opacity property.

Comment: you should get upvotes for this. The question asks about a CSS animation polyfill, and you are providing a polyfill required for the animation polyfill.

Comment: I am really surprised why this user has got +5 upvotes (50 points of reputation) for this  wrong answer! It is even more than by accepted answer!